# margin of nested elements

Tags: html, css

I need CSS code to place all elements with some indents, example first element must place on the left part of page, than image with some  indent and etc.

```
<div class="container-fluid">    
  <div class="row header_row">
   <div class="col-md-12">           
       <a href="main.html">Main</a>
       <img src="images/rose+garland.png" class="navi_images">
       <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
       <img src="images/rose+garland.png" class="navi_images">
       <a href="#">Contacts</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: so use margin and float and padding, where is the problem?

Comment: The question is a little hard to understand.  Are you trying to create a multi-column layout in Bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: is it a good idea to set 5 column, each for one element ? is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read about how [margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) and [padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) are made in CSS. If you want to place your elements next to each other you can use [`display: inline-block`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) or [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp). You will find enough examples when you search for spacing or positioning with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

if you using bootstrap you can learn complete code from following :
[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
[Bootstrap Components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)